# find by name or by grep

Tags: grep, find, solaris

```
find . -perm -u+x,g+x,o+x -type f -exec grep -i -l -H -E '#!/bin/bash|#!/bin/sh' {} \; 2>/dev/null 1>/$user_scripts
```

I am tasked with finding any script that could exist for N users in 4 folders. I will be using ssh and executing the command above to generate a list of files for later use. Some scripts with the file extension .sh and .bash which do not contain #!/bin/bash|#!/bin/sh are not found.

I need to improve upon this but I am struggling to find something that works in the Solaris server which I have no admin rights for (No special software / libraries). If possible I would prefer not to need to execute another script that would needlessly appear in each list for each user.

Basically I need some kind of "If(find or grep)" in the same line. Is this possible?

Comment: Use the `-o` (logical or) argument to `find`, perhaps? Thus, after the `;` ending `-exec`, you'd say `-o -name \*.bash -o -name \*.sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by OR-ing different parts of your `find` command. Consider splitting your selection criteria into three parts: necessary requirements for all files (permissions, etc), and then EITHER named files OR those with an appropriate header.

This can be expressed with `find` like this (split onto multiple lines here for readability only):

```
find . -perm -u+x,g+x,o+x -type f \(
    -name '*.sh' -o
    -name '*.bash' -o
    -exec grep -il -E '^#!/bin/bash|^#!/bin/sh' {} \;
\) 2>/dev/null >/$user_scripts
```

Comment: This works well however there are underlying complications with my command. I cannot use -E in my version of Solaris and I need to constrain the search to find only scripts the current user can execute. Nevertheless this answer pointed me in the right direction, thanks! @roaima

Comment: @JaredTS486 Use `egrep`  instead of `grep -E`